# How do I import my SCSS styles as a string in Webpack 5?

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I'm currently working on a browser extension and I need to import some of my SCSS styles as a string because I use the shadow dom. Right now my SCCS rule looks like this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ["css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"], 
  type: "asset/source"
}
```

I'm trying to use the [asset modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) as recommended by Webpack but it still does not work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar desire just now and spent a while staring at the [sass-loader documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#:%7E:text=//%20Translates%20CSS%20into%20CommonJS) and realized that the trick is not to use the `css-loader`, whose role is to convert the generated CSS into a CommonJS module. We both want the output of `postcss-loader`, which is still CSS:

```js
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  type: "asset/source",
  use: ["postcss-loader", "sass-loader"], 
}
```

Then, in my source, I can say...

```js
import styles from "./styles.scss";

// styles is now a string!
```